# how to get minutes from two different date in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am having fields called 'timestamp','onlineuser' from table called 'User'. I need to select onlineuser who is having the timestamp which is less than 5 minutes between NOW(),timestamp.
For example, timestamp will be like 2011-06-20 16:02:22.
I tried with mysql query , but seems wrong. kindly help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE timestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But NOW() should be first, like 'SELECT first_name,email FROM jobs_users WHERE NOW() >= timestamp - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE'.